# Large VIDEO File Upload using Httpclient does not work on Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, httpclient

Any Help or insight would be much appreciated.

What I have managed to obtain is that the issue is related to HTTPS as I am able to receive a 200 back when posting to an HTTP endpoint, similar to the following thread [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58824#c0)

Currently having a difficult time trying to resolve the following issue:

I'm using the AndroidClientHandler HttpClient implementation as well as the NativeTLS 1.2+ for the SSL/TLS Implementation

When I record a Video on my app that is longer than 1 min, or larger than 20MB I receive the following error:
     "Cannot access a disposed object.\nObject name: 
     'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'."

Here is the Method

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadVideo(string endPoint)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;
        try
        {
            //Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

            IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> formFields = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            messageHandlerService = Mvx.Resolve<IMessageHandlerService>();

            //Declare a scope whereby you can use resources and once you leave the scope the resources are disposed of.
            using (StreamReader reader = pathService.GetStreamReaderByPlatform())
            {
                client = await MyHttpClient.GetClientAsync();
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(500);

                var bytes = default(byte[]);
                using (var memstream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    reader.BaseStream.CopyTo(memstream);
                    bytes = memstream.ToArray();

                    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                    {
                        var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
                        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                        {
                            FileName = ".mp4",
                        };
                        content.Add(fileContent);
                        content.Add(EncodeFields(formFields));

                        await Policy.Handle<TimeoutException>()
                          .Or<HttpRequestException>()
                          .Or<IOException>()
                          .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => httpStatusCodesToRetry.Contains(r.StatusCode))
                          .WaitAndRetryAsync
                          (retryCount: 3,
                           sleepDurationProvider: retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
                           onRetry: (ex, time) =>
                           {
                               Debug.WriteLine($"Something went wrong: {ex.Exception.Message}, retrying...");
                           }).ExecuteAsync(async () =>
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine($"Trying to fetch remote data...");
                            responseMessage = await client.PostAsync(endPoint, content);
                            return responseMessage;
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException webx)
        {

            if (responseMessage == null)
            {
                responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
            }

            responseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            responseMessage.ReasonPhrase = string.Format("RestHttpClient.SendRequest failed: {0}", webx);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (responseMessage == null)
            {
                responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
            }

            responseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            responseMessage.ReasonPhrase = string.Format("RestHttpClient.SendRequest failed: {0}", ex);
        }

        return responseMessage;
    }
```

---

Below is the Stack Trace:

"  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.EndWrite (System.IAsyncResult r) [0x000b8] in <5a97d41d36694fb19855c17429527b10>:0 \n  at System.IO.Stream+<>c.b__53_1 (System.IO.Stream stream, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 \n  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Func`3[System.IO.Stream,System.IAsyncResult,System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult].invoke_TResult_T1_T2(System.IO.Stream,System.IAsyncResult)\n  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1+FromAsyncTrimPromise`1[TResult,TInstance].Complete (TInstance thisRef, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] endMethod, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00000] in :0 \n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 \n  at System.Net.Http.MultipartContent+d__8.MoveNext () [0x0025d] in <996a681f30a44cd685a4da54e11956e2>:0 \n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 \n  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__64.MoveNext () [0x0036e] in <996a681f30a44cd685a4da54e11956e2>:0 \n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 \n  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <996a681f30a44cd685a4da54e11956e2>:0 \n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1
…

Comment: Can you `curl` the same size file to your web server? If so have you tried a different  http-based client, like okhttp, in your program?

Comment: Also copying large content into a memory stream seems less optimal.

Comment: I am surprised by the fact that he is not going OOM after converting a memory stream supposedly that big.

Comment: following other comments, what is obvious old low heap size android is running out of memory holding your large file and your object is disposed/cleaned from memory. think about a solution like snot loading whole file but splitting in memory chunks when sending.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, Ive been considering chunk upload and I believe it may be the best route. I

Comment: @Cheesebaron what would be a more optimal way to read in the file to a byte[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by setting some flags in the Project Build Settings within Xamarin.Android.

Contrary to what the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=macos) suggest, setting the following configuration allows for me to POST the file to my server using HTTPS. While using the Native TLS 1.2+ crashes on uploads larger than 20MB...yes our server supports TLS 1.2

[image]