# HTTP Request Exception Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am sending a large video file (average file size of 50mb) to my server using **HttpClient** and **PostAsync**. I am getting an exception *(see below for full exception details)*. I found a article that the maximimum file size that can be handled is 1mb or less is this true? If so, how can I increase the maximum file size?

> {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.IO.IOException: Error writing request ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The socket has been shut down
>     at System.Net.WebConnection.EndWrite (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, System.Boolean throwOnError, System.IAsyncResult result) [0x000cc] in <2016f34fb49d404d9e9f5c5e62749987>:0 
>     at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.WriteAsyncCB (System.IAsyncResult r) [0x00013] in <2016f34fb49d404d9e9f5c5e62749987>:0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.EndWrite (System.IAsyncResult r) [0x000b8] in <2016f34fb49d404d9e9f5c5e62749987>:0 
>     at System.IO.Stream+<>c.b__53_1 (System.IO.Stream stream, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Func`3[System.IO.Stream,System.IAsyncResult,System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult].invoke_TResult_T1_T2(System.IO.Stream,System.IAsyncResult)
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1+FromAsyncTrimPromise`1[TResult,TInstance].Complete (TInstance thisRef, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] endMethod, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00000] in :0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in :0 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in :0 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in :0 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__64.MoveNext () [0x0036e] in :0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__64.MoveNext () [0x00489] in :0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in :0 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in :0 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in :0 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <df077aeeed724748974ac70c763795f3>:0 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <e4f3fb4cf2054f718c1099b587ec6f1e>:0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <df077aeeed724748974ac70c763795f3>:0 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <df077aeeed724748974ac70c763795f3>:0 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <df077aeeed724748974ac70c763795f3>:0 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <df077aeeed724748974ac70c763795f3>:0 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at TBSMobile.View.MainMenu+d__22.MoveNext () [0x00b96] in C:\Users\lawre\source\repos\TBSMobile\TBSMobile\TBSMobile\View\MainMenu.xaml.cs:1088 }

```
byte[] crVideoData;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(crvideo))
{
    crVideoData = File.ReadAllBytes(crvideo);
}
else
{
    crVideoData = null;
}

try
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(crvideo))
    {
        var vidlink = "http://" + ipaddress + Constants.requestUrl + "Host=" + host + "&Database=" + database + "&Contact=" + contact + "&Request=Lqr9fy";
        string vidcontentType = "application/json";
        JObject vidjson = new JObject
        {
           { "CAFNo", crcafNo },
           { "CAFDate", crcafDate },
           { "Video", crVideoData }
        };

        HttpClient vidclient = new HttpClient();
        var vidresponse = await vidclient.PostAsync(vidlink, new StringContent(vidjson.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, vidcontentType));

        if (vidresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            await conn.QueryAsync<CAFTable>("UPDATE tblCaf SET LastSync = ? WHERE CAFNo = ?", DateTime.Parse(current_datetime), crcafNo);
        }
    }
    else
    {
         await conn.QueryAsync<CAFTable>("UPDATE tblCaf SET LastSync = ? WHERE CAFNo = ?", DateTime.Parse(current_datetime), crcafNo);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Crashes.TrackError(ex);
}
```

Comment: @Laserence : Hope this link helps , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51866321/large-video-file-upload-using-httpclient-does-not-work-on-xamarin-android/51884248#51884248

Comment: are you sending data in chunks?

Comment: @G.hakim no bro can you remote my computer see whats wrong?

Comment: @G.hakim I am send the whole byte array I tried Krunal's suggestion now there is no exception but the video is not created

Comment: Well I cannot remote right now but I can give you a suggestion link check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-large-files-to-mvc-webapi-using-partitioning/) where the guy is sharing the large file as partitions or data chunks

Comment: @G.hakim can you help me with this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121773/how-to-enable-switch-on-multi-select-listview-with-binding-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

If your are saving the uploaded video in server using api, May be your max request length smaller than your uploded video size. If you want to upload high size video, Then increase the max request length in your webconfig file. Here is the sample code for increasing max request lenght in web api project.

```
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="15200" />
```

Comment: My problem now is the video is creating in the server side, I can send now the data but the server side wont create the file itself I think because of tls 1.0 Configuration. I am using PHP to receive the data