# How to enable switch on multi-select listview with binding in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I found this [article/sample code](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Todo/Todo/Views/TodoListPage.xaml.cs) it is how to make a to-do list. If you browse the code it is using bindings to determine if the task is done or not. What I am trying to accomplish is the same concept as the to-do list.

Please visit my [Github](https://github.com/lawrence317/TBSApp/tree/master/TBSApp/TBSApp) Repository for my full code:

Here is my app logic:

1. Upon loading of the application the app will show all the list of activities (e.g. Walking, climbing, rafting, etc.).
2. The user will select 1 or more activities.
3. The user will save the form in the local database.
4. If the user wants to remove or update an activity they have chosen the user will go to the list of forms they have submitted and when the user chose what form the want to update the user will be redirected to the list of activities with the switch of the activities they have chosen (**meaning the activities stored in the activities selected table**) enabled.

Basically like a to-do list. When the user checked what activities have already done the state will be checked or not. I don't have much knowledge in bindings I am having a hard time to implement it on my application.

Here is my XAML Code:

```
<ListView SeparatorVisibility="None" x:Name="lstActivity" ItemSelected="lstActivity_ItemSelected" HasUnevenRows="True">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame StyleClass="lstframe" CornerRadius="0" BorderColor="Transparent" HasShadow="False">
                     <StackLayout StyleClass="lstContainer" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                          <Grid>
                             <Label StyleClass="lstActivityName" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ActivityDescription}">
                                  <Label.FontFamily>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                             <On Platform="Android" Value="Poppins-Regular.otf#Poppins-Regular"/>
                                        </OnPlatform>
                                   </Label.FontFamily>
                             </Label>
                             <Switch Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" IsToggled="{Binding Selected}" />
                           </Grid>
                      </StackLayout>
                 </Frame>
             </ViewCell>
       </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Here is how I list all the activities without enabled state:

```
var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
var conn = db.GetConnection();

var getActivity = conn.QueryAsync<ActivityTable>("SELECT * FROM tblActivity WHERE Deleted != '1' ORDER BY ActivityDescription");
var resultCount = getActivity.Result.Count;

if (resultCount > 0)
{
   result = getActivity.Result;
   lstActivity.ItemsSource = result;

   lstActivity.IsVisible = true;
}
else
{
    lstActivity.IsVisible = false;
}
```

Here is my ActivityTable Class (Here is where I store the list of the activity):

```
namespace TBSApp.Data
{
    [Table("tblActivity")]
    public class ActivityTable
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string ActivityID { get; set; }
        public string ActivityDescription { get; set; }
        public string RecordLog { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastSync { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public int Deleted { get; set; }
        public int Checked { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my CAFActivityTable (Where I store the selected activity):

```
[Table("tblCAFActivity")]
public class CAFActivityTable
{
    public string CAFNo { get; set; }
    public string ActivityID { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastSync { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public int Deleted { get; set; }
    public int Checked { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have?  What is it doing (or not doing)?

Comment: I cant pattern the binding in the code of the article to my code

Comment: I am not going to read their entire article and then analyze why your code isn't working like theirs is.  What **specifically** isn't working?  All the bindings?  Just some of them?

Comment: @Jason Not the entire article just the part will put the binding for enable or disable that I can't do

Comment: Are you talking about binding the IsToggled property of the Switch?

Comment: @Jason yes, how can I do it?

Comment: @Jason can you show me how to properly do it?

Comment: You can refer this: https://xamarinhelp.com/multiselect-listview-xamarin-forms/ if it helps you.

Comment: @MShah I want to update list of activities I saved in my local database. For instance I saved 3 activities in my CAFActivityTable and I want to add more but the problem is I want the list all the activities then toggle the switch of the activities that is in CAFActivityTable

Comment: Read the comments and the question yet could not understand the exact issue can you brief me in please!?

Comment: @G.hakim I want to list all the activities from ActivityTable when the page is loaded but the switch of the activity is toggled when the activity is in CAFActivityTable. I can list all of the activities the only problem is how to toggle the switch when the activity is in CAFActivityTable

Comment: So on the basis of a particular condition you want your switch to be enabled?

Comment: @G.hakim yes the switch will be enabled when the activity is in CAFActivityTable

Comment: So why not just check if it is available in the `CAFActivityTable` using `LINQ` and on the basis of this set a boolean and then bind that boolean to the Switch?

Comment: @G.hakim can you show me how?

Comment: @G.hakim Please I really need your help

Comment: Do you have a collection of both these classes?

Comment: @G.hakim What do you mean collection?

Comment: a `List` or an `ObservableCollection` or something like that, what kind of data do you have available

Comment: @G.hakim i think i dont have that

Comment: What data do you have of types `CAFActivityTable` and `ActivityTable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have bound the Switch's `IsToggled` to your model's `Selected`. So your `ActivityTable` model should contain a bool value `Selected` property:

```
public class ActivityTable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string activityDescription;
    public string ActivityDescription
    {
        get => activityDescription;
        set
        {
            if (activityDescription != value)
            {
                activityDescription = value;
                onPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    bool selected;
    public bool Selected
    {
        get => selected;
        set
        {
            if (selected != value)
            {
                selected = value;
                onPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void onPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You could change the switch's state through `Selected` after implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

**Update:**

Compare the elements in `ActivityTable` to the items in `CAFActivityTable`. When you find the item has the same ActivityID, change the current item's selected state:

```
var activityItems = await ActivityConnection.Table<ActivityTable>().ToListAsync();
var CAFItems = await CafConnection.Table<CAFActivityTable>().ToListAsync();

foreach (var item in activityItems)
{
    foreach (var CAFItem in CAFItems)
    {
        if (item.ActivityID == CAFItem.ActivityID)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
// Bind your list view's items source to this activityItems
// If you want to update the database use the code below
await ActivityConnection.UpdateAllAsync(activityItems);
```

Comment: Where do I put this?

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto This is your `ActivityTable` model. When you used `conn.QueryAsync<ActivityTable>()` to retrieve the database data, you need a model to present them.

Comment: https://github.com/lawrence317/TBSApp/tree/master/TBSApp/TBSApp - please see this link for my full code

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto I can't remote your pc. But I will look into your project later.

Comment: The name of the page is under View Folder the file name is PageCAF.xaml and PageCAF.xaml.cs

Comment: Thank you I have been struggling with this for a week now

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto I'm still confused about what issues you are facing? You have bound your Switch's `IsToggled` to `Selected`. I can't log in your project as it requires a password and userid. Do you have a sample to specify your issue? And please describe more details about your problems.

Comment: I want to update list of activities I saved in my local database. For instance I saved 3 activities in my CAFActivityTable and I want to add more but the problem is I want the list all the activities then toggle the switch of the activities that is in CAFActivityTable

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto If the activities have been stored successfully, it should be listed correctly. Can you post the corresponding code with the screenshots(what is displayed now and what you expected it to be)?

Comment: I dont have the corresponding code because I dont know how to start it. How can I list all the activities in ActivityTable and enable the switch of the activity when the activity is in CAFActivityTable?

Comment: is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto I'm really confused about your issues now. You listed the elements in `ActivityTable` but you wanted to change the state in another table called `CAFActivityTable`. You just shared an entire project without describing which part occurs error. There're too many codes in your project and I can't log in it as it requires a user and password. I think you could open a support ticket here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6

Comment: Here is the main thing I want to achieve  I want to list all the activities from ActivityTable when the page is loaded but the switch of the activity is toggled when the activity is in CAFActivityTable. I can list all of the activities the only problem is how to toggle the switch when the activity is in CAFActivityTable

Comment: How can I list the items with a query because I need a specific items to list

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto Then add the query as you want: `var activityItems = await ActivityConnection.Table<ActivityTable>().Where(x => x.LastUpdated == ...).ToListAsync();`. I think it's the same thing. I just posted a sample, you should modify it following your own requirement.